# ¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo un fichero con este contenido:

```
Hola qué tal
Yo \t muy bien
    Un placer.
```

Quiero leerlo línea a línea, guardando el valor de cada línea en una variable para procesarlo.

Es decir, quiero:

- Leer la primera línea.
- Realizar la asignación del valor "Hola qué tal" a la variable $linea.
- Hacer cosas con `$linea`.
- Leer la segunda línea.
- Asignar el valor "Yo \t muy bien" a `$linea`.

Y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Utiliza `while ... do ... done < fichero` con algún matiz:

```
while IFS='' read -r linea || [[ -n "$linea" ]]; do
    printf ">%s<\n" "$linea"
done < fichero
```

Lo que se explica como:

- `IFS=''` (o `IFS=`) impide que se eliminen los caracteres de espacio (espacio o tabulador) iniciales o finales.
- `-r` impide que la contrabarra (`\`) se interprete como un carácter especial.
- `|| [[ -n $linea ]]` impide que se ignore la última línea si no termina con `\n` (pues `read` devuelve un exit no-cero cuando encuentra un EOF). Teóricamente, una línea debe terminar con `\n` y así [lo define POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206): *Secuencia de cero o más caracteres distintos de una nueva línea `\n` seguido de un carácter de nueva línea*. Sin embargo, puede darse el caso que se haya escrito un fichero en el que la última línea no lo contenga; con esta adición, también se procesaría dicha línea.

Así, en tu fichero tendríamos esta salida:

```
$ while IFS= read -r linea || [[ -n "$linea" ]]; do printf ">%s<\n" "$linea"; done < fichero
>Hola qué tal<
>Yo \t muy bien<
>   Un placer.<
```

---

Veamos qué pasaría si elimináramos alguna de las comprobaciones:

**Sin `IFS=''`**: se eliminan los espacios iniciales y finales.

```
$ while read -r linea || [[ -n "$linea" ]]; do printf ">%s<\n" "$linea"; done < a
>Hola qué tal<
>Yo \t muy bien<
>Un placer.<      # ¡esto tenía espacios al principio!
```

**Sin `-r` en `read`**: se interpreta la contrabarra.

```
$ while IFS= read linea || [[ -n "$linea" ]]; do printf ">%s<\n" "$linea"; done < a
>Hola qué tal<
>Yo t muy bien<   # ¡aquí había un \t!
>   Un placer.<
```

**Sin `|| [[ -n $linea ]]`**: una hipotética última línea no terminada en `\n` no se leería:

Dado el fichero anterior, si le añadimos una nueva serie de caracteres sin `\n` final:

```
$ printf "ueee" >> fichero
```

Observamos que su contenido aparece de esta forma:

```
$ cat -vet fichero
Hola quM-CM-) tal$
Yo \t muy bien$
   Un placer.$
ueee              # se superpone al prompt
```

Cuando leemos, esta última línea no se procesa:

```
$ while IFS= read -r linea; do printf ">%s<\n" "$linea"; done < fichero
>Hola qué tal<
>Yo \t muy bien<
>   Un placer.<   # la línae ueee" no se lee
```

---

Referencias:

- [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- [What does IFS= do in this bash loop: `cat file | while IFS= read -r line; do … done`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26480210/1983854)
- [Read a file line by line assigning the value to a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10929511/1983854)