# copiar archivos que contienen palabras desde un archivo txt

Tags: string, grep

necesito copiar archivos que contienen palabras contenidas en un archivo txt.  Por ejemplo el archivo que tengo contiene:

```
Balaena_mysticetus
Balaenoptera_acutorostrata
Bos_taurus
Canis_familiaris
Delphinapterus_leucas
Equus_caballus
Eschrichtius_robustus
Homo_sapiens
Lipotes_vexillifer
Loxodonta_africana
Mus_musculus
Myotis_lucifugus
Orcinus_orca
Physeter_catodon
Sus_scrofa
Tursiops_truncatus
tsg_637
```

Quiero copiar archivos que contengan todas las palabras registradas en el txt.

He intentado utilizando:

```
grep -L "Balaena_mysticetus"
```

- pero en vez de la palabra recibir un archivo como input

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Comment: Te recomiendo separar tu archivo filtros por el char '|' (Pleca), en ves de un Enter, posteriormente intenta realizar el comando: egrep  -r  '{tus filtros}'  {Path donde deseas buscar}

Comment: egrep? or grep?

Comment: egrep, Igual puede seguir este  [tutorial](https://paraisolinux.com/10-usos-para-grep/)

Comment: Igual para poder copiar todo lo que tienes en el archivo.txt (Filtros), puedes ejecutar los siguientes comandos: filtos=$(cat {Path donde esta tus archivos de filtros})

Comment: y luego egrep -r "$filtos" {Path donde deseas buscar}

Comment: lo conseguí con el siguiente comando fgrep -l -f  sp_cetacea  OG_tsg/* | xargs cp -t output/

Comment: no entiendo: ¿buscas archivos que contengan _todas_ las palabras o archivos que contengan _alguna_ de las palabras?

Comment: Tienes el Archivo.txt (Separado por los |), Ese archivo te permite listar aquellas palabras que quieras que busque. Posteriormente ejecutas el comando egrep, en la cual buscará por los filtros que indicaste.

Comment: @diegoorellana no hace falta eso. `grep` tiene el parámetro `-f` que te permite dar un archivo como origen de los patrones. Así, puedes decir `grep -f patrones.txt fichero` y buscará en `fichero` todas las líneas que tengan alguno de los patrones que salen en `patrones.txt`.

Comment: y si quiero que cada fichero tenga sí o sí las palabras almacenadas en patrones.txt?

Comment: todas las palabras

Answer (score 1):

Buen día! con éste código en Bash puedes hacer lo que necesitas:

```
#!/bin/bash
for line in $(cat PATH_DE_ARCHIVO_CON_PALABRAS); do
    for file in $(grep -ril ''$line PATH_ARCHIVOS_DONDE_BUSCAR_PALABRAS); do
       cp $file PATH_DONDE_SE_COPIARAN_ARCHIVOS
    done
done
```

En resumen, en la primer línea se recorren todas las palabras de tu archivo donde estarán contenidas las palabras a buscar.

En la segunda línea, se busca con un GREP la palabra leída del archivo en el directorio donde estarán los archivos que posiblemente contendrán la palabra en cuestión. (el -ril es para que busque en sub-directorios, traiga solamente la ruta del archivo donde encuentra la palabra)

En la tercer línea lo que se hace es copiar a un cierto directorio el archivo que en la línea anterior se encontró como que contiene esa palabra.

*Veo que se podría quitar el segundo FOR, optimizando más el script, aun así, es entendible y a mi me sirvió.

Saludos!

Comment: lo de `for line in $(cat PATH...); do ... done` es algo frágil. Siempre se recomienda usar el bucle `while` y decir `while IFS= read -r linea; do ... cosas con "$linea"; done < PATH...`. Más en [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83).

Comment: En efecto, el script es un ejemplo "rápido" y por ende, tiene mucho de donde mejorarse. Si había leído algo sobre el ciclo a utilizar en lectura de archivos, sería cuestión de agregárselo para un mejor funcionamiento, Saludos!

Comment: Si te interesa el tema, hay un espléndido manual: [Why you don't read lines with "for"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor). Veo que eres nuevo, ¡bienvenido! Utiliza [edit] para añadir y mejorar tus publicaciones.

Comment: Excelente!, lo repasaré más tarde, ahora estoy en el trabajo.. y sí, soy novato aún en el tema :) Gracias @fedorqui

Comment: lo que necesito es que se muestren los archivos que contienen TODAS las palabras almacenadas en un archivo de texto.