# ¿Cómo puedo indicar en qué línea de un archivo está la cadena dada?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Me piden hacer un script el cual me pida el nombre de un usuario del sistema el cual introduzco por consola.

Una vez tiene el nombre tengo que hacer que lea el archivo passwd linea por linea y cuando encuentre el usuario que yo le he introducido me diga "El usuario esta en la linea $linea"

O sea que tengo que hacer un contador, un for y un if dentro pero no me funciona, lo que tengo es esto:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Introduce el usuario para saber su posicion"
read user
contador=0
    for lista in `more /etc/passwd`;
    do
        contador=`expr $contador + 1`

        if [ "$user" -eq "$lista" ];
        then
            echo "El usuario $user esta en la linea $contador"
            exit
        else
            echo "El usuario no se encuentra en el sistema"
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score 2):

En [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83) se explica cómo procesar un fichero línea a línea.

En tu caso dado, se trataría de hacer:

```
while IFS='' read -r linea || [[ -n "$linea" ]]; do
    printf ">%s<\n" "$linea"
done < /etc/passwd
```

Sin embargo, en tu caso concreto quieres saber en qué línea está y, por ello, necesitas un contador. Además, quieres mirar el usuario, por lo que puedes leer específicamente la primera columna indicando que el separador es ":" con `IFS=':'` y `read -r usuario resto`. Con ello, `$usuario` guardará este valor:

```
contador=0
visto=0
while IFS=':' read -r usuario resto || [[ -n "$linea" ]]; do
    ((contador++))
    if [ "$usuario" = "$usuario_dado" ]; then
        printf "usuario %s en línea %d\n" "$usuario" "$contador"
        visto=1
        break
    fi
done < /etc/passwd

[ "$visto" -eq 0 ] && printf "no se ha encontrado\n"
```

De todos modos, con Awk sería inmediato:

```
awk -F: -v usuario="$usuario_dado" '$1 == usuario_dado {print "línea", NR}' /etc/passwd
```

---

¿Por qué no funcionaba tu versión? Pues porque estás comparando con `-eq`, que es para enteros:

```
$ us="hola"
$ [ "$us" -eq "hola" ] && echo "si"
-bash: [: hola: integer expression expected
```

Las comparaciones de cadenas se hacen con `[ "$var1" = "$var2 ]`:

```
$ [ "$us" = "hola" ] && echo "si"
si
```

Answer (score 1):

El comando grep ya tiene la opción de darte el número de linea.

```
~$ grep -n root /etc/passwd 
1:root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
11:operator:x:11:0:operator:/root:/sbin/nologin
36:satelliteroot:x:9003:9003::/home/satelliteroot:/bin/bash
~$ grep -n root /etc/passwd | awk -v FS=":" '{print $1}'
1
11
36
```

Si hubiera mas de una coincidencia podrías hacer que cogiera la primera o la última con head o tail

```
~$ grep -n root /etc/passwd | awk -v FS=":" '{print $1}' |head -1
1
~$ grep -n root /etc/passwd | awk -v FS=":" '{print $1}' |tail -1
36
```