# ¿Cómo puedo leer una cadena de texto, leyendo sus caracteres de tres en tres?

Tags: bash

¿Cómo se puede leer una cadena de texto, leyendo sus caracteres de tres en tres?

Concretamente busco leer los trinucleótidos de una secuencia de ADN, y poder contar cuantos hay.

Sea una cadena:

```
AAGACAGAGTAGACAAGTACAGTAGACAGATGACGGGTAGCAT
```

me gustaría dividirla en

```
AAG
ACA
GAG
...
```

Pero el problema es que no tengo un delimitador para utilizar el comando `cut`.

¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?

El lenguaje de programación que uso es Bash.

He intentado los siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(cat $1|wc -m)
b=$(cat $1)
for ((i=0;i<$a;i=i+3));do
        echo ${b:i:(i+3)}
done
```

Pero me imprime desde tres hasta el final toda la cadena, no de tres en tres. El argumento `$1` es un archivo que contiene la secuencia ADN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El tercer parámetro de la expansión es la longitud del recorte y no la posición final de éste. Puedes consultarlo en la ayuda con [`man bash`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash):

> `${parameter:offset:length}`
>
> **Substring Expansion.** Expands to up to `length` characters of `parameter` starting at the character specified by `offset`. If `length` is omitted, expands to the substring of `parameter` starting at the character specified by `offset`. `length` and `offset` are arithmetic expressions (see ARITHMETIC EVALUATION below).

En castellano:

> `${parámetro:inicio:longitud}`
>
> **Expansión de Subcadena.** Expande hasta `longitud` caracteres de la cadena `parámetro` comenzando por el carácter cuya posición está especificada por `inicio`. Si se omite `longitud`, expande a la subcadena de `parámetro` comenzando en el carácter especificado por `inicio` hasta el final. `longitud` e `inicio` son expresiones aritméticas (ver EVALUACIÓN ARITMÉTICA más abajo).

Por lo que tu código quedaría:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(cat $1|wc -m)
b=$(cat $1)
for ((i=0;i<$a;i=i+3));do
   echo ${b:i:3}
done
```

---

Si lo que quieres es contar los trinucleótidos, podría bastarte con calcular `($a + 2) / 3`:

```
#!/bin/bash
b=$(<"$1")
a=${#b}
echo "Número de trinucleótidos: $(((a + 2) / 3))"
for ((i=0; i<$a; i=i+3))
do
    echo ${b:i:3}
done
```

Quiero resaltar el uso de `$(<"$1")` para cargar el contenido de un archivo en una variable (entre comillas para dar soporte a archivos con espacios en blanco) y el de `${#b}` para obtener la longitud de una variable.

---

Si únicamente te interesa el cálculo del número y en ningún momento te interesa mostrar su contenido, entonces es mejor hacer:

```
#!/bin/bash
NUM=$(wc -c < "$1")
echo "Número de trinucleótidos: $(((NUM + 2) / 3))"
```

O, de manera reducida, `$((( $(wc -c < "$1") + 2) / 3))`.

Notar el uso de `wc -c < [archivo]` para evitar que aparezca el nombre del archivo junto con el resultado de la cuenta.

Hay que tener en cuenta que `wc -m` es mucho más lento que `wc -c` en archivos muy grandes porque no requiere leer su contenido para contar caracteres multibyte. Una letra `ñ` es un carácter, pero ocupa dos bytes en un archivo codificado en UTF-8.

Además habría que tener en cuenta que ambos (`-m` y `-c`) contarían todos los avances de línea (`\n`) si los hubiera.

Answer (score 2):

Utiliza `grep` para que recorte la cadena en bloques de tres:

```
$ echo "123456789" | grep -o '...'
123
456
789
```

Como `.` coincide con cualquier caráter, la expresión regular `...` coincide con tres caracteres. Usando la señal `-o` de `grep` conseguimos que cada resultado se muestre en una línea diferente, por lo que luego puedes hacer lo que quieras con ello: contar líneas, sumar...

También incluso puedes decir lo siguiente, utilizando la *process substition* para hacer como si [leyeras un fichero línea a línea](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/129806/83):

```
while IFS= read -r tri; do
    echo "--- $tri"
done < <(grep -o '...' <<< "123456789")
```

Y así poder trabajar con cada trinucleótido en cada iteración:

```
$ while IFS= read -r tri; do echo "-- $tri"; done < <(grep -o '...' <<< "123456789")
-- 123
-- 456
-- 789
```

En tu caso:

```
$ echo "AAGACAGAGTAGACAAGTACAGTAGACAGATGACGGGTAGCAT" | grep -o '...'
AAG
ACA
GAG
TAG
ACA
AGT
ACA
GTA
GAC
AGA
TGA
CGG
GTA
GCA
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar `sed` o `awk`

#### Con sed.

```
$ sed -r 's/(.{3})/\1\n/g' <<< "abcdefghi"
```

Aquí la expresión regular hace match con cada tres caracteres `(.{3})` y luego, a ese grupo, le añade un salto de línea `\1\n`.

#### Con awk.

```
$ awk -v FS="" '{
    for (i=1; i<=length($0); i++) {
        printf $i
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            printf "\n"
    }
}' <<< "abcdefghi"
```

Donde se redefine el *field separator* a nada para que itere sobre caracteres. Y, durante el loop, cada número de caracter módulo 3, imprime un salto de línea.

En tu caso, usando la secuencia de bases nitrogenadas que mostraste.

```
$ awk -v FS="" '{
    for (i=1; i<=length($0); i++) {
        printf $i
        if (i % 3 == 0)
            printf "\n"
    }
}' <<< "AAGACAGAGTAGACAAGTACAGTAGACAGATGACGGGTAGCAT"
AAG
ACA
GAG
TAG
ACA
AGT
ACA
GTA
GAC
AGA
TGA
CGG
GTA
GCA
T
```

Parece que al final de lo que ingresaste "sobró" una timina.