# ¿Cómo crear usuarios a partir de datos en un texto?

Tags: shell-script

Tengo que hacer un script el cual haga usuarios a partir de un archivo de texto, la estructura del archivo es la siguiente:

```
84882667V:Barberan Neila, David
49432717J:Callejas Paytuví, Alfonso
74541195N:Camacho Ayuso-Morales, Alejandro
```

Necesito que el `DNI` sea el nombre de usuario y la contraseña que seria después de la coma.

Esto es a lo que he llegado:

```
#!/bin/bash

user=$(cut -c "1-9" -z  llistat1.txt)    
pass=$(cut -d "," -d " " -f 3 -z  llistat1.txt)

useradd $user -p $pass
```

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola. Bienvenido a [es.so].  Te recomiendo [edit] la pregunta agregando algo de información como que has probado o que has encontrado por Internet, y sería bueno que realices el [tour] y leer [ask]. La idea es ofrecer un [mcve] en todas las preguntas.

Comment: No entiendo lo de _la contraseña que seria después de la coma_. ¿La contraseña del primer usuario sería "David"?

Answer (score 0):

Primero hay que asegurarse que el separador de saltos de tu consola (la variable de entorno **IFS**) responde a saltos de linea.

```
IFS='
'
```

Luego debes recorrer el archivo con un for:

```
for $linea in $(cat lista1.txt); do
```

luego, puedes ir "recortando" cada linea con cut, como has hecho en tu ejemplo:

```
$user=$(echo $linea | cut -d: -f1);
$pass=$(echo $linea | cut -d, -f2);
```

y por ultimo creas el user:

```
useradd $user -p $pass
```

no te olvides de cerrar el bucle:

```
done;
```

Comment: uy lo de `for $linea in ...` es mala práctia. Mira [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83)

Comment: hola @fedorqui. No veo por que es mala practica lo del for. Puedes explicarlo? en el enlace solo habla de usar while, no for... Aparte que conocemos el formato del archivo, y se entiende que cada linea que nos ha puesto esta separada por un salto \n.

Comment: Imagina que el archivo contiene dos líneas "hola" y "que tal". Si haces `for linea in $(cat fichero); do echo "$linea --"; done` observas que el "que tal" se interpreta separándolo, de manera que primero tratará "que" y después "tal". Es decir, esta manera de hacer es incorrecta si el fichero contiene líneas con espacios por ejemplo.

Comment: eso no es cosa del`for` exclusiva. Lo que comentas tiene que ver con la configuracion de IFS, que gestiona precisamente la separacion de elementos.  Lo actualizo en la respuesta.

Comment: Puede, pero no deja de ser un parche. Mira [Why can't you use cat to read a file line by line where each line has delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17102151/1983854): mejor un _while_ de toda la vida.

Comment: No es un parche. Para algo existe esa variable IFS. pues eso. mejor un `for` de toda la vida :)

Comment: Sería útil si fuera un _for_ de toda la vida a secas, pero resulta que: 1) obligas al usuario a que defina IFS, algo que probablemente pocos conozcan a este nivel. 2) cargas todo el fichero en memoria, luego es poco escalable. Por ello, sigo apostando por usar el _while_ que indiqué en mi primer comentario.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes ni siquiera usar un script, sino un one liner; por lo que al principio puede ser engorroso pero muestra otra opción.

```
$ echo '84882667V:Barberan Neila, David
49432717J:Callejas Paytuví, Alfonso
74541195N:Camacho Ayuso-Morales, Alejandro' | \
sudo xargs -I {} bash -c "
usuario=\$( awk -v FS=: '{print \$1}' <<< '{}' )
passwd=\$(awk -v FS=, '{print \$2}' <<< '{}')
useradd \$usuario
chpasswd <<< \"\$usuario:\$passwd\""
```

Si pones ese one-liner te crea los usuarios con su contraseña como lo indicaste, en este caso use un `echo` en lugar de un archivo.

Un problema en ese formato es el espacio inmediatamente después de la coma, ya que sería incluida en la contraseña.

Una forma de eliminar ese problema puede ser con una regex (pero es mejor que normalices tu archivo de usuarios).

```
$ echo '84882667V:Barberan Neila, David
49432717J:Callejas Paytuví, Alfonso
74541195N:Camacho Ayuso-Morales, Alejandro' | \
sudo xargs -I {} bash -c "
usuario=\$( grep -Po '^.*(?=:)' <<< '{}' )
passwd=\$(grep -Po '(?<=, ).*' <<< '{}')
useradd \$usuario
chpasswd <<< \"\$usuario:\$passwd\""
```

Este último one-liner elimina el caso del espacio después de la coma pero lo supone.
El resultado de cualquiera de esos comandos lo puedes ver de esta manera.

```
$ getent passwd | tail -n 3
84882667V:x:1019:1028::/home/84882667V:
49432717J:x:1020:1029::/home/49432717J:
74541195N:x:1021:1030::/home/74541195N:
```

Ahi puedes ver que los usuarios se crearon y con una contraseña (indicada por el caracter "x").

Ahora, yendo a lo del archivo, supón que tienes tu archivo "llistat1.txt" de la forma

```
84882667V:Barberan Neila, David
49432717J:Callejas Paytuví, Alfonso
74541195N:Camacho Ayuso-Morales, Alejandro
```

Es decir, con un espacio y luego el nombre, entonces puedes correr cualquiera de los 2 one-liners mostrados arriba.

Es decir, con este, pero tomando en cuenta el problema del espacio inicial en la contraseña.

```
$ sudo xargs -I {} bash -c "
usuario=\$( awk -v FS=: '{print \$1}' <<< '{}' )
passwd=\$(awk -v FS=, '{print \$2}' <<< '{}')
useradd \$usuario
chpasswd <<< \"\$usuario:\$passwd\"" < llistat1.txt
```

O este, tomando en cuenta que que la contraseña asignada al usuario ya no tendrá el espacio inicial.

```
$ sudo xargs -I {} bash -c "
usuario=\$( grep -Po '^.*(?=:)' <<< '{}' )
passwd=\$(grep -Po '(?<=, ).*' <<< '{}')
useradd \$usuario
chpasswd <<< \"\$usuario:\$passwd\"" < llistat1.txt
```

Lo que hacen los one-liners es leer linea por linea el contenido de tu archivo y lo pasan a una subshell y, en esencia, dentro de cada una se extraen (más adelante especificaré un poco) el usuario y la contraseña para luego utilizar `useradd` para añadir el usuario y `chpasswd` para cambiar su contraseña en modo batch.

El procesamiento por `awk` es sencillo, simplemente recibe un renglón y cambia un separador, ya sea por coma `,` o los dos puntos `:` y luego selecciona el campo y lo almacena, ahi el problema con el espacio, ya que el segundo campo, después de la coma, inicia con un espacio y luego la contraseña.

El procesamiento por `grep -Po` le dice que va a utilizar una expresión regular compatible en Perl, y el parámetro `-o` indica que solo va a imprimir el patrón encontrado, y no la linea entera.

Las expresión regular `'^.*(?=:)'` indica que el patrón a encontrar es lo que esté iniciando y que se encuentre antes de dos puntos.

La exprexión regular `'(?<=, ).*'` indica que el patrón a encontrar es aquello que se encuentre después de una coma y un espacio.

Corriendo cualquiera de los one-liners mostrados, podrás entrar al usuario con `sudo su nombre_del_usuario` y, una vez loggeado, probar la contraseña con un `sudo ls` y verás lo que comento sobre el espacio.

Además, quizás deberías agregarles una shell o un espacio de trabajo a cada usuario con los parámetros `-m` y `-s` en `useradd`.

Comment: ese `xargs -I {} bash -c` que lanza dos awks cada vez me parece matar moscas a cañonazos :) ¿No sería mejor un `while IFS=: read -r nombre pass...`?

Comment: Jaja, claro. Pero me gusta la artillería, además, me gusta mucho que siempre se puede paralelizar.