# script para buscar palabras en un texto txt pero quiero hacerlo sin usar el comando grep

Tags: linux

Quiero hacer un script bash  en linux para   encontar palabras en una archivo txt sin usar grep ni sed,  pretendo  leer un archivo y definir el archivo  como una variable y después leerlo, leer linea por linea y cuando le de una variable(palabra) me diga si esta en el texto y en que linea se encuentra.
Tengo idea de hacer un ciclo pero no se como construirlo.

les agradecería su ayuda.

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83). Podrías leer en un array y validar cada campo. De todos modos, no tiene mucho sentido hacerlo sin grep. ¿Qué problema real quieres solucionar? ¿Por qué grep no es una opción? Además, sería bueno que indicaras qué has intentado.

Comment: Puedes usar otras herramientas? `perl`? `awk`? `cut`? En general, usar bash así [es muy mala idea](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/). Y como se define la palabra? SI buscas _comes_ y encuentras _comestible_ cuenta?

Comment: Hola, en este sitio se ayuda a resolver dudas, no se hacen ejercicios o scripts

Comment: muchas gracias, @fedorqui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sé que no se debe de hacer código para otros y que sólo es un sitio para dudas específicas sobre material trabajado, como bien lo comentaron. Sin embargo me tomé el atrevimiento de programarlo, aunque insisto, como lo han descrito en los comentarios, que usar `bash` para hacer lo que otros programas pueden hacer mejor y más rápido es mala idea en términos de eficiencia, pero no en términos de ocio (y más si estás lidiando con el desempleo o subempleo).

```
#!/bin/bash

declare _archivo="archivo1.txt"
declare _frase="frase2 a encontrar"

declare -i _contador_lineas=0


echo Buscando en archivo: "$_archivo"

while read -r linea || [[ -n "$linea" ]]  #  Lee linea por linea mientras haya
                                          #+ y no sea nula.
do
    (( _contador_lineas++ ))  # Aumentamos en uno cada que entre.

    [[ "$linea" == *$_frase* ]] \
        && echo Ocurrencia de: "\"$_frase\"" encontrada en linea: $_contador_lineas
    #  Con el comparador == y el glob *,
    #+ busca la frase sin importar lo que tenga
    #+ antes o despues

done < "$_archivo"  # Alimentamos al while con el contenido del archivo.
```

Supón que a ese archivo le llamas "buscador.sh" y le das permisos de ejecución con `chmod u+x buscador.sh` y tienes un archivo llamado `archivo1.txt` en el mismo directorio donde tienes ese archivo con el siguiente contenido:

```
uno dos
dos
tres
escombros frase a encontrar mas escombros
linea 5
qwer  sadf 
escombros frase2 a encontrar mas escombros
escombros frase2 a encontrar mas escombros
linea 9
escombros frase2 a encontrar mas escombros
linea 11
linea 12
linea 13
escombros frase2 a encontrar mas escombros
```

El resultado obtenido al ejecutar el programa sería el siguiente:

```
$ ./buscador.sh
Buscando en archivo: archivo1.txt
Ocurrencia de: "frase2 a encontrar" encontrada en linea: 7
Ocurrencia de: "frase2 a encontrar" encontrada en linea: 8
Ocurrencia de: "frase2 a encontrar" encontrada en linea: 10
Ocurrencia de: "frase2 a encontrar" encontrada en linea: 14
```