# ¿Cómo busco los ficheros cuyo nombre termina en un texto determinado?

Tags: bash, bucle-for, shell-script

Tengo un script con una serie de terminaciones de nombre de archivos en un txt (un nombre parcial de archivo por línea, siempre es la parte final del archivo)

Ejemplo:

```
00037d62.mp3
00037a1f.mp3
0003dd4c.mp3
0003dd56.mp3
000340e4.mp3
```

Un nombre real de archivo podria ser "Héroes del Silencio - Entre dos tierras 0003dd4c.mp3"

Se debe mostrar las rutas de donde se encuentra coincidencia con cada una de las terminaciones del TXT. Dicho de otro modo, buscar los archivos que acaben como en el fichero txt. Se debe buscar partiendo de la ruta base. Os pongo el script

```
#!/bin/bash
# Definimos variable rutas 
$PATH_BASE="/Script/musica/canciones/" 
$PATH_TXT_TAKEDOWNS="/Script/musica/takedowns/" 
$FILES_TAKEDOWNS=""

# Listamos los ficheros que tiene la carpeta de takedowns 
$FILES_TAKEDOWNS=$(cat $PATH_TXT_TAKEDOWNS*.txt)

 # Recorremos cada uno de los nombres de ficheros de los diferentes txts 
for f in $FILES_TAKEDOWNS
         do
                 # Si longitud cadena es mayor que 1
                 if [ ${#f} -gt 1 ];
                 then
                        # Hacemos find del archivo en la base musical
                        ruta_busqueda_fichero=$(find $PATH_BASE -name *$f)
                        #este echo deberia mostrar la ruta de cada busqueda de los ficheros pero por alguna extraña razon, solo muestra vacio
                        echo "Ruta $ruta_busqueda_fichero"
                        # Si descomento esta linea muestra correctamente la sitaxis find para cada uno de los archivos
                        # echo "find $PATH_BASE -name *$f"
                 fi
       done
```

He intentado probar el bloque este por separado:

```
ruta_busqueda_fichero=$(find $PATH_BASE -name *$f)
echo "Ruta $ruta_busqueda_fichero"
```

en otro script asignadole valores a las variables $PATH_BASE y  $f con valores concretos y funciona correctamente, el echo muestra la ruta de la búsqueda. Pero necesito usarlo dentro del bucle `for`.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de fichero txt? ¿Se supone que los archivos están dentro de `$PATH_BASE`? ¿Por qué usas `*` en `
-name *$f`, el nombre no es exactamente ese?

Comment: Porque el nombre del fichero puede contener mas cosas en el nombre ("loquesa esto o lo otro 00037d62.mp3"). Lo que si se incluye si o si es un identificador, una especie de hash único justo antes de la extensión del fichero.Ejemplo : 00037d62.mp3
Por eso empleo el comodín * delante de la variable $f

Comment: ¿Has comprobado si realmente existen tales ficheros?

Comment: actualiza tu pregunta, porque no queda claro realmente. Dices que el archivo .txt contiene nombres de archivo, pero luego en el comentario indicas que es un "prefijo".

Comment: he actualizado la pregunta, aclarando ese tema @Jakala  , sigo estancado y no localizo el fallo del porque no se muestra el resultado del find fedorqui . Gracias a los dos por responder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que indicas:

- El fichero contiene los sufijos del archivo
- Deben buscarse en todo el directorio

Por ello, yo haría:

```
while IFS= read -r sufijo; do
    [ ${#sufijo} -le 1 ] && continue  # saltamos si contenido es 0 o 1 caracteres
    ficheros=$(find $PATH_BASE -name "*$sufijo")
    # echo "Rutas $ficheros"  # debería analizarse qué hacer si hay más de uno
done < fichero.txt
```

Véase [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83) para más detalles sobre la sintaxis de lectura del fichero.

Lo que hacemos es saltar las líneas con 0 o 1 caracteres. Para el resto, hacemos el `find` que indicabas, pero con el añadido que hacemos `find dir/ -name "*$sufijo"` y es importante poner las comillas para evitar problemas con espacios.

---

Ejemplo con GNU Bash 5.0:

```
$ pwd  # estoy aquí
/tmp/bl

$ ls *  # tengo unos cuantos ficheros
a.sh        bbADIOS.mp3 fichero.txt

bla1:
lasjdflaksHOLA.mp3

bla2:
pasodfiweADIOS.mp3

$ cat fichero.txt  # y estos sufijos
HOLA.mp3
ADIOS.mp3
ADEU.mp3

$ cat a.sh   # el script lo configuro así
PATH_BASE="/tmp/bla/"

while IFS= read -r sufijo; do
    [ ${#sufijo} -le 1 ] && continue  # saltamos si contenido es 0 o 1 caracteres
    ficheros=$(find $PATH_BASE -name "*$sufijo")
    echo "Rutas $ficheros"  # debería analizarse qué hacer si hay más de uno
done < fichero.txt

$ bash a.sh   # y me devuelve esto
Rutas /tmp/bla//bla1/lasjdflaksHOLA.mp3
Rutas /tmp/bla//bla2/pasodfiweADIOS.mp3
/tmp/bla//bbADIOS.mp3
Rutas
```

Comment: He probado la solución que propones pero si descomento la linea de echo no me muestra la ruta del fichero. ¿que puede suceder?

Comment: @mulhacen oh, había un error en el condicional. Revisa ahora a ver

Comment: En cualquier caso, siempre puedes poner `echo "find $PATH_BASE -name *$sufijo"` para ver qué está haciendo.

Comment: esa es la historia , si hago el echo del comando lo muestra todo correctamente. He puesto varios echos y muestra lo siguiente ```COMANDO: find /home/Script/musica/ -name *00026601.mp3
RUTA BUSCADA:  SUFIJO FICHERO:00026601.mp3 ```

El comando lo muestra bien, el sufijo del fichero tambien correcto pero la ruta buscada que seria $ficheros no muestra nada

Comment: @mulhacen recuerda poner las comillas para que busque "*00026601.mp3", por seguridad. Después, `var=$(comando)`, es decir `listado=$(find ...)`.

Comment: tambien seria bueno que el patron del archivo empiece por */, porque sino podria darse el caso de encontrar archivos que acaben en el sufijo, tipo ASDF00026601.mp3...y por lo que entiendo solo deberia encontrar 00026601.mp3, no?

Comment: @Jakala por la explicación dada en la pregunta entiendo que eso es precisamente lo que se busca, ficheros que terminen en esto, no los que tengan nombre exactamente así.

Comment: en su primera linea de la pregunta dice que el contenido del txt son nombres de archivo, no "sufijos" de nombres de archivo... "un nombre de archivo por linea"

Comment: @Jakala oh, tienes razón, lo entendí mal. Corrijo

Comment: si, en realidad el for es para recorrer cada uno de esos ficheros y los subfijos o partes del nombre de ficheros a buscar. En el ejemplo de fedorqui se hace para un único fichero, pero me da igual, en eso no tengo problema.

La clave esta en guardar el resultado del find y mostrarlo por pantalla, que por alguna razón sigo sin conseguir que se visualice.

Comment: @mulhacen la verdad es que resulta bastant extraño. ¿En qué sistema operativo y versión de Bash trabajas?

Comment: Utilizo Debian

Linux 4.19.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.98-1
GNU bash, versión 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Lo único que me queda seria probar el script en otra maquina con otra versión.

Comment: @mulhacen he añadido un ejemplo desde cero, creando ficheros, directorios, etc. Te animo a probar algo simple como lo que yo hice. No puedo hacer más

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Acabo de probar los archivos y el script en una instalación limpia de Debian 10.3 y funciona correctamente.

No se que puede suceder en la maquina original. Tratare de actualizar los paquetes a ver, es algo bastante raro, no le ecuentro explicacion....

Comment: @mulhacen qué bien! Lo mismo tienes algún alias o alguna configuración extraña de Bash, mira a ver el `~/.bashrc` por si te da alguna pista. A todo esto, mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y si te solucionó el problema, considera aceptar la respuesta. Un saludo!