# ¿Por qué sed da el error "uso inválido de la dirección de línea 0"?

Tags: python, bash, sed

Me gustaría extraer cada línea de un archivo txt y exportarlo a otro archivo txt, pero me aparece un error en el sed.

Este es el bucle:

```
import os
lineas=len(open('hola.txt').readlines())

for x in range(lineas):
    x=(str(x))
    os.system('sed -n '+x+'p hola.txt > disp'+x+'_ping.txt')
```

Este es el error que me indica la terminal:

```
sed: -e expresión #1, carácter 2: uso inválido de la dirección de línea 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que le pasas 0 como primer numero de linea a `sed` y `sed` no sabe contar desde 0, cuenta desde 1. Debe ser:

```
for x in range(lineas):
    os.system(f"sed -n '{x + 1} p' hola.txt > disp{x + 1}_ping.txt")
```

o mejor:

```
for x in range(1, lineas + 1):
    os.system(f"sed -n '{x} p' hola.txt > disp{x}_ping.txt")
```

No obstante, lo haces de una forma muy ineficiente al leer el archivo completo en memoria mediante `readlines` solo para obtener el número de lineas.

Una forma mucho más eficiente es:

```
with open("hola.txt", "r") as achivo:
    lineas = sum(1 for linea in archivo)
```

o usando un subproceso y `wc`:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

output_nlines = subprocess.run(
    shlex.split("wc -l hola.txt"),
    capture_output=True
    ).stdout
lineas = int(output_nlines.split()[0])
```

No obstante un par de alternativas para hacer lo que buscas que creo que son un poco más directas:

### Usando subprocesos

Creo que `awk` es una opción más simple en éste caso:

```
import subprocess
import shlex

subprocess.run(shlex.split("awk '{ print $0 > \"disp\"NR\"_ping.txt\"}' hola.txt"))
```

### Usando Python solo

```
with open("hola.txt", "r") as input_file:
    for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
        with open(f"disp{i + 1}_ping.txt", "w") as output_file:
            output_file.write(line)
```

Posiblemente sea algo más lento, pero es independiente del sistema operativo, por lo que funcionará allí donde Python funcione.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo, quieres escribir cada línea de un archivo en un archivo cuyo nombre contenga ese número.

Es decir, dado "hola.txt" con este contenido:

```
1hola
2adios
3adeu
```

Quieres tres ficheros:

```
# disp1_ping.txt
1hola
# disp2_ping.txt
2adios
# disp3_ping.txt
3adeu
```

Si es así, creo que usar Python para lanzar luego Sed es bastante poco productivo. Primero, porque Python solo puede gestionarlo perfectamente, como se ve en [la respuesta de FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/361528/83). Después, porque hay herramientas que te lo hacen más rápidamente desde línea de comandos.

Veamos cómo hacerlo con Bash:

```
i=0
while IFS= read -r linea
do
    echo "$linea" > disp${i}_ping.txt
    ((i++))
done < fichero
```

Esto usa [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83) y pone un contador para saber en qué línea estamos (ajusta el valor inicial a 0 o 1 según necesites). Luego, escribe cada línea en el fichero `disp${i}_ping.txt`, cuyo valor será `disp1_ping.txt`, `disp2_ping.txt` y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 0):

En tu código, `len()` devuelve la longitud de una cadena, por lo que la variable `lineas` será de tipo entero. Obviamente no vas a poder iterar lo que quieres sobre ese valor. Por otro lado si `x` representa una línea de la variable `lineas`, entonces quiere decir que ya es un string, no tienes que convertirlo `x=(str(x))`

```
import os

with open('hola.txt', 'r') as reader:
    for x in reader.readlines():
        os.system(f'sed -n {x}p hola.txt > disp{x}_ping.txt')
```