# ¿Por qué la contraseña definida con "useradd" no coincide con la que le pasé al comando?

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell, shell-script

Me pidieron en un examen realizar un script en bash que poniendo como parametros un archivo de texto y un nombre de grupo creara usuarios con los datos contenidos en el archivo de texto.

Ejemplo de entrada del fichero alumnos.txt:

```
juanmanuel;delrio;delafuente;77776666T
ander;errasti;basterretxea;77778888X
```

Se crearan dos usuarios con la siguiente informacion:

- juanmanuel y clave: 77776666T
- ander y clave: 77778888X

Al script se le pasaran los siguientes parametros:

```
./altaalumnos.sh alumnos.txt curso2
```

donde  altaalumnos.sh es el nombre del script, alumnos.txt es el fichero que contiene los datos separados por ";" y curso2 es el nombre del grupo al que perteneceran los alumnos

Bien, adjunto el codigo:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -z $1 ];then
   echo "No ha ingresado ningun archivo de texto"
elif [ -f $1 ];then

   group=$(cat /etc/group | grep "$2")
   if [ "$group" ];then
      lineas=$(wc -l $1 | cut -d\  -f1) #numero de lineas que tiene alumnos.txt
      for (( i = 1; i <= $lineas; i++ )); do
         sudo useradd -g $2 $(cat $1 | head -n $i | tail -1 | cut -d\; -f1) -p $(cat $1 | head -n $i | tail -1 | cut -d\; -f4)
      done
      echo "Usuarios creados con exito."
   else
      echo "El grupo $2 no existe."
      echo "Creando el grupo $2 ..."
      sudo groupadd "$2"
      echo "Grupo $2 creado."
      echo "Creando usuarios..."
      lineas=$(wc -l $1 | cut -d\  -f1) #numero de lineas que tiene alumnos.txt
      for (( i = 1; i <= $lineas; i++ )); do
         sudo useradd -g $2 $(cat $1 | head -n $i | tail -1 | cut -d\; -f1) -p $(cat $1 | head -n $i | tail -1 | cut -d\; -f4)
      done     
   fi
else
    echo "No existe el archivo de texto $1 ." 
fi
```

Despues de ejecutar el codigo con el comando:

```
chmod +x altaalumnos.sh
./altaalumnos.sh alumnos.txt curso2
```

hago:

```
cat /etc/passwd
```

y veo que los usuarios juanmanuel y ander han sido creados y ambos pertenecen al mismo grupo. Ahí todo bien, el problema es que cuando quiero cambiar de usuario para saber si la contraseña es la del .txt hago el comando:

```
su juanmanuel
```

pongo la contraseña 77776666T pero me indica fallo de autentificacion y con ander lo mismo. He probado a poner otros datos en el .txt como: daniel;garcia;perez;1234 y me sigue dando el mismo fallo.

Comment: Te recomiendo leer [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83) para evitarte todos estos `cat | head | cut...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un fallo muy común, para setear el password debes encriptarlo cuando hagas useradd, a continuación te dejo un pedazo del manual.

```
-p, --password PASSWORD
The encrypted password, as returned by crypt(3). The default is to disable the password.
Note: This option is not recommended because the password (or encrypted password) will be visible by users listing the processes.

You should make sure the password respects the system's password policy.
```

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias, luego lo pruebo!!

Answer (score 2):

Esta respuesta es una continuación de lo que comento @r4ziel en la suya.

La razón es que la contraseña que escribes '77776666T' tendría que ser esa encriptada por algún algoritmo de cifrado.

Una herramienta que nos puede ser útil es `mkpasswd`.

Pongamos el caso de que queremos que la contraseña sea '77776666T', entonces operemos:

```
$ pass_usuario_pass='77776666T'
$ pass_usuario_pass_encrypted=$(mkpasswd -m sha-256 -sS 'AAAFFF444' <<< "$pass_usuario_pass");
$ sudo useradd juanmanuel  -g grupo2 -p "$pass_usuario_pass_encrypted"
```

Y eso sería todo. El usuario tendría que estar agregado con la contraseña "77776666T".

El algoritmo de encriptación que le pedimos implementar al programa `mkpasswd` es el de **SHA-256**, además de que, con el parámetro `-S` le agregamos un *salt* para aumentar la seguridad de nuestra contraseña.

Algo que nos podría interesar sería revisar la cadena comparada con lo que se almaceno en la información de dicho usuario, es decir, la cadena cifrada la tendríamos que tener así:

```
$ echo "$pass_usuario_pass_encrypted"
$5$AAAFFF444$ZaLKaef1LXBGLfQKJ6yO4ul1IDeEe.3mQxw0cXCGzg
```

Y esa información debería ser un pedazo de lo que nos muestra la salida del archivo `/etc/shadow`

```
$ sudo getent shadow juanmanuel | awk -F : '{print $2}'
$5$AAAFFF444$ZaLKaef1LXBGLfQKJ6yO4ul1IDeEe.3mQxw0cXCGzg.
```

Es decir:

```
$ [[ "$(sudo getent shadow juanmanuel | awk -F : '{print $2}')" ==  "$pass_usuario_pass_encrypted" ]] \
  && echo Misma contraseña \
  || echo Diferente contraseña
Misma contraseña
```

Lo cual refuerza nuestro conocimiento de que la contraseña que se ingresó en el parámetro `-p` al usar `useradd` se almacenó en texto en el archivo `/etc/passwd`.

Esto es sabiendo que en `shadow(5)` se establece que el segundo campo del archivo es la contraseña encriptada.

> ### Description
>
> ```
> (...)
> Each line of this file contains 9 fields, separated by colons (“:”), in the 
> following order:
>
> login name
>
> (...)
>
> encrypted password
>
> (...)
> ```

Comment: @Daniel Juape marca esta respuesta como favorita, ya que tiene mucho más detalle y será más útil para futuras consultas. Gracias!