# ¿Qué significa el parámetro en un =" 0"?

Tags: linux, bash, condiciones, unix, grep

estaba revisando un código en Bash y veo esto `if [ "$existe" = "0" ]; then`. ¿Qué significa ese 0?

```
existe=$(grep ^[aeiou] -c nombre.txt)
if [ "$existe" = "0" ]; then
echo "usted no escribió ninguna palabra con vocales"
else
for linea in $(cat nombre.txt | grep ^[aeiou])
do
echo "$linea estos nombres empiezan con vocal"

done
fi
```

Comment: La respuesta más corta es que ese "0" es sólo un número y la pregunta se contesta entendiendo que hace `grep` con el parámetro `-c`.

Comment: lo que dice @Cuauhtli. Además, este script está lleno de cosas poco edificantes para alguien que empieza con Bash. Si quieres mirar si un fichero tiene alguna línea que empieza con vocal, puedes decir directamente `if grep -q "^[aeiou]" fichero; then ...; fi`. Luego para leer un fichero línea a línea el bucle con `for` es peligroso, mucho mejor usar [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83)

Answer (score 3):

El parametro -c del comando grep especifica como resultado el número de líneas del archivo que contienen el patrón especificado.

En este caso, el if comprueba si te ha devuelto 0 (es decir, si no ha encontrado las vocales). En caso de que el resultado sea 0, te nuestra el mensaje oportuno.

Echa un vistazo al manual de grep: https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html

Answer (score 1):

Según la documentación de [grep](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/grep1.html) el primer comando `grep ^[aeiou] -c nombre.txt` busca aquellas palabras que inicien con vocales dentro del archivo `nombre.txt`, en caso de encontrar el patrón, con la bandera `-c` indicas que en lugar de mostrar las coincidencias, muestre el conteo de las coincidencias.

Luego ese resultado se almacena en `existe`, y dentro del if evaluas que si `existe = 0` (es igual a 0), quiere decir que no hubo coincidencias.

Para el caso en que `existe != 0` sea distinto de cero, entonces hubo coincidencias y lo que sigue es mostralas en pantallla.

Answer (score 1):

Tu script mira si en un fichero "nombre.txt" existen líneas que empiecen por vocal. Si es así, dice cuáles; en caso contrario, dice que no hay.

El script cumple su cometido, pero contiene muchas cosas mejorables. Por ejemplo, ¿por qué revisar dos veces el fichero si con una hay suficiente?

Propongo esta otra opción, en la que voy acumulando en un array las líneas "interesantes" y luego reviso su contenido para ver si hay o no líneas del tipo:

```
# Defino array
lineas=()

# Itero el fichero línea a línea
while IFS= read -r linea;
do
    # Reviso si una línea empieza por vocal o no
    if [[ "$linea" =~ ^[aeiou] ]]; then
       # Si empieza por vocal, la añado al array
       lineas+=("$linea")
    fi
done < fichero


# Miro tamaño del array e imprimo su contenido
if [ "${#lineas[@]}" -ge 1 ]; then
    echo "estos nombres empiezan con vocal:"
    printf "%s\n" "${lineas[@]}"
else
    echo "usted no escribió ninguna palabra con vocales"
fi
```

Nótese que la iteración sobre un fichero se hace según lo estándar explicado en [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83).