# Crear usuarios a partir de un fichero en Shell

Tags: bash, shell, programación-bajo-nivel

Este sería el fichero:

> nombre, apellido1, apellido2
>
> pepe, perez, perez
>
> pepa, perez, perez

Tengo que crear usuarios a partir del fichero, el usuario tiene que estar formado por las tres primeras letra de nombre y del primer apellido, es decir, si el `nombre=pepe` y `apellido=hernandez`, deberá ser pepher.

Si el fichero consta de una línea es fácil, pero cuando consta de tres me resulta difícil.

Hago el `case` ya que si hay login duplicados añado un número secuencial.

Este es mi código:

```
#!/bin/bash

for name in `cut -d"," -f1 /home/osboxes/Documents/ScriptEjemplos/fichero.csv`;do
 
lar1=${name:0:3}

done

for apellido in `cut -d"," -f2 /home/osboxes/Documents/ScriptEjemplos/fichero.csv`;do
  
lar2=${apellido:0:3}

done

login=$lar1$lar2

largT=${#login}

((largR=largT-1))

ultcar=${login:largR:1}

case $ultcar in

  [0-9]) ((ultcar++))

         Nuevolog=${login:0:${largR}}$ultcar ;;

  *)     Nuevolog=${login}0 ;; 

esac 

echo $Nuevolog
```

Comment: puedes mostrar un ejemplo de como lo has intentando hacer

Comment: Te muestro la respuesta en las respuestas de mi pregunta, he querido mostrarte una captura

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Perdona soy nuevo en este sitio, pero de todas formas he subido una captura con el código que tengo hecho. Muchas gracias por el feedback :)

Comment: Piensa en qué pasa si alguien te daba la respuesta en una imagen y te pone a transcribir, la imagen no muestra algún caracter o algo y no puedes usar la respuesta. Pues eso, no uses imágenes si puedes usar texto, hazlo bien para que los demás confíen en que también los vas a ayudar (y te ayuden). Puedes editar ahora mismo TU RESPUESTA, ponerla como texto y marcarla como aceptada si es la solución, etc. para que otros la puedan usar también. Ya lo de hacer una pregunta mejor formulada, es una recomendación para las próximas. Haz el recorrido y revisa cómo preguntar :)

Comment: Recomiendo leer [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83) para evitar distintas malas prácticas en este código, que también indica muy claramente https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Hay muchas piezas de tu pregunta que ya se han respondido aquí y allá. Al fin y al cabo, se trata de leer un fichero, crear una cadena y luego ejecutar un comando. Por ello, sería mejor dividir la pregunta en estas partes e incorporar lo que tengas de cada una de ellas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Basandome en lo que comentas y entiendo que requieres, te comparto el código modificado.*

```
#!/bin/bash

fichero=/home/osboxes/Documents/ScriptEjemplos/fichero.csv
strNombres="";

for name in `cut -d"," -f1 $fichero`;do
    strNombres="$strNombres $name";
done

strNombres="${strNombres#"${strNombres%%[![:space:]]*}"}";  #Borramos el espacio que queda al inicio de nuestra cadena
nombres=(${strNombres});                                    #Convertimos la cadena en un arreglo
lengthName="${#nombres[@]}";                                #Obtenemos el tamaño de nuestro arreglo de nombres

strApellidos="";

for apellido in `cut -d"," -f2 $fichero`;do
    strApellidos="$strApellidos $apellido";
done

strApellidos="${strApellidos#"${strApellidos%%[![:space:]]*}"}";    #Borramos el espacio que queda al inicio de nuestra cadena
apellidos=(${strApellidos});                                        #Convertimos la cadena en un arreglo
lengthSurnames="${#apellidos[@]}";                                  #Obtenemos el tamaño de nuestro arreglo de apellidos

#Creamos un for en el cual vamos a obtener tanto el nombre como el apellido correspondiente

for (( i=0; i<$lengthName; i++ ));do
    lar1=${nombres[$i]:0:3}

    if [[ $i -le $lengthSurnames ]]; then
        lar2=${apellidos[$i]:0:3}
    fi

    echo "Nombre: ${nombres[$i]} - Apellido: ${apellidos[$i]} : lar1: $lar1 - lar2: $lar2";

    login=$lar1$lar2
    largT=${#login}
    echo "login: $login";
    echo "largT: $largT";

    ((largR=largT-1))
    echo "largR: $largR";

    ultcar=${login:largR:1}
    echo "ultcar: $ultcar";    
    case $ultcar in
            [0-9]) ((ultcar++))
            Nuevolog=${login:0:${largR}}$ultcar ;;
        *)  Nuevolog=${login}0 ;;
    esac

    echo "Nuevolog: $Nuevolog";
    echo "";
done
```

***NOTA:** Te recomiendo revisar el case, ya que estás intentando validar que si un caracter es un número entre 0 y 9 y nunca va a ingresar allí.*

*Espero te sirva*

Comment: Recomiendo leer [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83) para evitar distintas malas prácticas en este código, que también indica muy claramente https://www.shellcheck.net

Comment: Muchisimas gracias de verdad, funciona perfectamente.