# Recorrer el crontab mediante Script shell unix

Tags: script, shell, unix, cron

Estoy intentando revisar unos **backups** que se lanzan via **CRON** y quiero lanzar un Script que lea desde un TXT en cada linea la palabra a buscar en el crontab, si aparece un resultado es que el backup se esta realizando.

Pero no lo consigo hacer, siempre me dice que NO se esta realizando, he probado varias formas, la única en la que almenos se ejecuta sin errores, aunque siempre me dice que no, es la siguiente:

```
while IFS= read -r line
 do
   crontab -l | grep -i $line
   
   if [ $? = 0 ]; 
   then
        echo SI QUE Existe Backup de $line
    else
        echo No existe backup de $line
    fi
done < listado.txt
```

Comment: Interesante leer también [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83)