# bucle for en bash para recorrer filas de un dataset

Tags: bucle-for, bash

Tengo un dataset y quiero recorrer cada una de las filas, comprobar si el valor de una columna está vacío y en caso de que sí, rellenarlo.

Estoy teniendo el problema de que no encuentro la forma de encontrar cómo recorrer las filas con un `for` en bash.

Sería esto correcto?

```
for i in wc-l file
```

Estoy buscando en la web que muestro, pero no consigo encontrar la estructura adecuada. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129805/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-leer-el-contenido-de-un-fichero-l%c3%adnea-a-l%c3%adnea-con-bash)

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar', creo que no pero debo mirarlo con detalle y ponerme a ello