# Recorrer una lista en bash

Tags: lista, bash

me gustaría saber como puedo recorrer una lista de un archivo .txt dentro de un bucle para poder utilizar comandos con los elementos que tengo en la lista.

contenido del txt:

```
azulo
rojo 
verde
```

y que el script me de esto:

```
echo "azul"
echo "rojo"
echo "verde"
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/129805/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-leer-el-contenido-de-un-fichero-l%c3%adnea-a-l%c3%adnea-con-bash)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suponiendo que el archivo esté en `/micarpeta/miarchivo.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash
archivo="/micarpeta/miarchivo.txt"
while IFS= read -r linea
do
  echo "$linea"
done < "$archivo"
```

## Código línea por línea

Asigna la ruta de tu archivo a la variable `archivo`:

```
archivo="/micarpeta/miarchivo.txt"
```

Es un ciclo `while` típico:

```
while IFS= read -r linea
```

La opción `IFS= <-(espacio en blanco)` antes de la lectura es para evitar recortar los espacios en blanco precedentes.

La opción `-r` del comando `read` como dice en la ayuda:

```
-r  do not allow backslashes to escape any characters
```

Es decir, sirve para evitar escapar caracteres con backslash `\`.

Necesario para el bucle en bash:

```
do
```

Muestra por pantalla el contenido de la variable `línea`:

```
echo "$linea"
```

Finalmente necesitas cerrar el loop con `done` ademas de alimentar al bucle con una [redirección](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html#REDIRECTION) de entrada con el contenido del "$archivo":

```
done < "$archivo"
```

Más info sobre read [aquí](https://linuxhint.com/while_read_line_bash/).

Comment: No entiendo muy bien esta parte :  while IFS= read -r linea y despues por que rediriges $archivo al done??

Comment: Ahí edito la respuesta para explicar un poco mejor.

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que tu contenido esta en archivo.txt

```
cat archivo.txt 
azulo
rojo 
verde
```

Puedes utilizar "sed" para realizarlo en una sola linea

```
sed -i 's,^\(.*\)$,echo "\1",g' archivo.txt
```

Y vuelve a verificar el resultado de tu archivo

```
cat archivo.txt 
echo "azulo"
echo "rojo "
echo "verde"
```