# ¿Cómo itero sobre los resultados de find?

Tags: linux, bash, bucles, find

No sé qué hago mal, pero esto no me funciona.

```
#!/bin/bash

basedatos = $(find /data -iname *.db)
for n_carpeta in ${basedatos[@]}
do
     echo "$basedatos\n";
done
```

Comment: Primero, quita los espacios a ambos lados del igual en la línea basedatos: `basedatos=$(find /data -iname *.db)`. Luego en el ciclo, imprime la variable de iteración: `echo "$n_carpeta"` no `echo "$basedatos\n";`. Aunque dejame decirte que lo que hace ese script puede resumirse a ejecutar `find /data -iname *.db`. No necesitas un ciclo para estar imprimiendo, ya `find` de por sí imprime.

Answer (score 3):

Para iterar sobre el resultado de `find` hay varios maneras, dependiendo de la complejidad de la expresión.

Si es solamente un patrón... usa globbing directamente:

```
for fichero in patron
do
    # cosas con "$fichero"
done
```

Por ejemplo, en tu caso:

```
for fichero in *.db
do
    # echo "$fichero"
done
```

Si la expresión es compleja, usa `find` y luego recógelo con un bucle `while` como en [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83):

```
find /data -iname *.db -print0 | 
    while IFS= read -r -d '' fichero; do 
        echo "$fichero"
    done
```

Answer (score 1):

Al definir una variable no puedes dejar espacios alrededor del `=`. Y estás imprimiendo el arreglo completo cada vez en vez de solo una carpeta

```
#!/bin/bash

basedatos=$(find /data -iname *.db)
for n_carpeta in $basedatos
do
     echo "$n_carpeta";
done
```

Comment: esto fallará si hay ficheros cuyo nombre contiene espacios