# ¿Cómo puedo leer un valor desde un fichero y pasarlo a una variable?

Tags: bash

Estoy intentando recoger un valor de un fichero llamado datos_rangos.txt y almacenarlos en una variable para sacar un número aleatorio entre los valores almacenados y meterlo a un array. Mi problema es que no consigo los números aleatorios porque (creo) que no consigo almacenar los valores del rango entre el que quiero aleatorizar los números en una variable. Lo que quiero saber es que estoy haciendo mal para que no funcione mi código y a ser posible una forma de arreglarlo.

Primero probé a guardar los valores usando los comandos: `'cut -d ";" -f1'` y `'cut -d ";" -f2'`

Después he probado con `$(cat datos_rangos.txt | awk -F ";" '{print $1}')` y `$(cat datos_rangos.txt | awk -F ";" '{print $2}')`

La parte de la función que estoy usando para esto es:

```
cat datos_rangos.txt | sed -i -n "1d"
num_particiones=0
particion_max=0
while read line
do
   if [[ $line =~ ";" ]];
   then 
       minpart=$(cat datos_rangos.txt | awk -F ";" '{print $1}')
       echo "--->$minpart<---"
       maxpart=$(cat datos_rangos.txt | awk -F ";" '{print $2}')
       echo "--->$maxpart<---"
   particion=$( shuf -i $minpart-$maxpart -n 1)
   particiones[$num_particiones]=$particion
   asignaciones[$num_particiones]=-1
   num_particiones='expr $num_particiones +1'
   fi
done<datos_rangos.txt
```

Los echos son para comprobar si me lee las variables que quiero usar como rangos.

El contenido del fichero datos_rango.txt es:

```
4|5
5;15
4_6
1:10:2:9:3:8:-24:9:4:6
```

Aunque solo me interesa la segunda línea para este caso.
En concreto al hacer el echo me lee como minpart 5 y la última línea y como maxpart me lee el 15 que es lo que quiero. Me gustaría que me leyese el 5 como minpart y el 15 como maxpart

Comment: Recomiendo enganchar el código en https://www.shellcheck.net, pues hay una serie de cosas peligrosas, otras extrañas y otras incorrectas en el código en sí. También recomiendo debugar y ver en qué punto falla. ¿`echo $particion` te da resultado? Debería.

Comment: Todo lo de `minpart=$(...)` lo podrías simplificar leyendo el fichero con `while IFS="|" read min max ; do echo "$min"; done < datos_rango.txt`. Véase [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83)

Comment: Luego `num_particiones='expr $num_particiones +1'` es incorrecto. Para guardar un resultado de un comando en una variable, debes decir `var=$(comando)`. Lo mismo confundiste con var=` comando `

Comment: La variable particion no contiene un valor aleatorio ya que $minpart no me lee el 5 del fichero .txt por eso mi problema.
Ahora probaré a leer el fichero de esa manera para ver si consigo avanzar, muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo mismo te sería útil leer directamente así: `while IFS=";" read min max ; do echo "$min"; done < <(grep ";" fichero)`. De este modo, al hacer `grep` te quedas únicamente con las líneas que tienen ";", que es al fin y al cabo lo que estás haciendo dentro con un "if".

Comment: También deberías definir el array inicialmente: `declare -A particiones`

Comment: El array lo tengo definido fuera de la función, por no copiar todo el código solo copié esa parte, teniéndolo definido fuera de la función no debería dar problema, verdad?

También he probado el comando del ```while IFS...``` , lo he editado un poco para adecuarlo a lo que busco y me ha funcionado a la perfección, muchísimas gracias, he estado varias horas intentando hacer esto de diferentes maneras.

Comment: No, no, para nada, simplemente lo comenté por si eso te daba problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando lo descrito en [¿Cómo puedo leer el contenido de un fichero línea a línea con Bash?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/129805/83), en comentarios a la pregunta hemos visto que esto funciona bien:

```
while IFS=";" read min max
do
    # cosas con "$min" y "$max"
done < <(grep ";" fichero)
```

Es decir, vamos leyendo el fichero línea a línea usando `;` como delimitador de campos y, por tanto, asignando a `$min` el valor del primer campo y `$max` al resto.

Además, "alimentamos" el bucle con `<(grep ";" fichero)`, que es una forma de decirle que solo entren en el bucle `while` las líneas que contienen un ";".